# ReactJS : Custom function triggers the re-render of memoized component

Tags: reactjs, render

I am creating an annual planning with a lot of cell and trying to fight against performance issues.

This is the global structure :

```
<IndividualPlanningContext>
  <Index>
    <Table>
      for each month : 
      <Month>
        for each day : 
          <Day />
      </Month>
    </Table>
  </Index>
</IndividualPlanningContext>
```

I need to handle some clicks from `<Day />` to open modals and get which period is selected. To avoid useless re-render I'm just passing necessary props down the three.

This is Index :

```
function Index() {

  const clickOnDate = (day, partOfDay) => {
    if (!getIsWorkablePartOfDay(day, partOfDay)) return;
    if (newHolidayStartParameters) {
      setNewHolidayEndParameters({ date: day, partOfDay: partOfDay });
      setOpenCreateHolidayModal(true);
      return;
    } else {
      setNewHolidayStartParameters({ date: day, partOfDay: partOfDay });
      return;
    }
  }

    return (
    <>
      {openCreateHolidayModal && (
        <CreateHolidayModal
          open={openCreateHolidayModal}
          startDate={newHolidayStartParameters.date}
          endDate={newHolidayEndParameters.date}
          onClose={() => {
            setOpenCreateHolidayModal(false);
            setNewHolidayStartParameters(null);
            setNewHolidayEndParameters(null);
          }}
          onSuccess={() => {
            setOpenCreateHolidayModal(false);
            setNewHolidayStartParameters(null);
            setNewHolidayEndParameters(null);
          }}
        />
      )}
      <div className="flex flex-col gap-5">
        <div className="text-3xl font-bold text-slate-600">Page title</div>
        <Button
          onClick={() => {
            clickOnDate(dayjs("2023-01-04"), "morning");
            clickOnDate(dayjs("2023-01-04"), "afternoon");
          }}
        >
          test
        </Button>
        <Paper
          elevation={2}
          className={`w-3/4 px-2 py-2`}
        >
          <Table clickOnDate={clickOnDate} />
        </Paper>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Then I'm propdrilling the clickOnDate function. When I click, it re-renders every single day cells wherease every child component after `Index` is memoized :

Example with Day :

```
const Day = memo(function Day ({ day, clickOnDate }) {
  ...
  return (
      <div
        onClick={() => clickOnDate(day, partOfDay)}
        onMouseEnter={() => handleMouseEnter()}
        onMouseLeave={() => setHovering(null)}
        className={`z-10 h-full ${
          shouldHighlight() && "bg-amber-100 text-slate-500"
        }`}
      ></div>
  ); 
}
```

The test button on Index didnt reproduce this behavior when commenting every props of clickOnDate so I guess it comes from the function probably having a different reference or something of this kind.

Then I tried with some states with useState(), and it didn't reproduce this behavior.

The question is : Why does my function triggers re-render of each day wherease they are memoized and that props are not supposed to change, and how can I work around this ?

My initial structure was using a context with all states, but it triggered too much re-renders.

EDIT :

After trying @Nazrul answer, this feels more performant, however the react profiler still indicates that every days are re-rendering when clicking on a day :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The clickOnDate function is defined within the Index component, and every time Index re-renders, a new function reference is created. May be because of this even if the Day component is memoized, it will receive a new callback function reference on each render of Index, causing the memoization to not work.
You can try useing the useCallback hook to memoize the clickOnDate function and ensure that it has a stable reference across renders. Try something like this,

```js
function Index() {
  const [openCreateHolidayModal, setOpenCreateHolidayModal] = useState(false)
  const [newHolidayStartParameters, setNewHolidayStartParameters] = useState(null)
  const [newHolidayEndParameters, setNewHolidayEndParameters] = useState(null)

  const clickOnDate = useCallback((day, partOfDay) => {
    // ...your existing clickOnDate logic
  }, [newHolidayStartParameters, setOpenCreateHolidayModal])
  return(
      //...your jsx
  )
```

Comment: When doing it this way, it feels better at usage, but strangely there are as much re-renders on react profiler tool... I can't understand what is going on

Comment: Furthermore, when I'm putting all the dependencies in the callback array, it starts lagging again ...